# setting spring boot logger to debug only for AOP related info

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-aop

I use the following configuration

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

to investigate in AOP related issues...is there any way to show in the log file only log entries related to AOP the same way as

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

but for AOP?

Comment: logging.level.org.springframework.aop=DEBUG does not do the job?

Comment: it works fine...thanks